# Adding a link to an image

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to add a link to an image using an input box, let say you have an image uploaded and you have an input,

```
Image Link: <input type="text" id="image_link"/>
```

in this box a user types in www.google.com
and you want the link to append to the image.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes there's a way. What do you have so far?

Comment: Not very clear what you want.

Comment: Do you want to create a new image? Or you have an image, and you want to do "When someone clicks on this image, they will go to that [link]"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/2QRBm/ ?

HTML:

```
<input/>
<button>set link</button>
<img src="http://media.heavy.com/post_assets/2010/03/0417/1267743226_stoned-party-dog-original.jpg" width="300"/>
```

Javascript:

```
$('img').wrap($('<a/>',{href:'',target:'_blank'}));

$('button').click(function(){
    var val=$('input').val();
    $('img').closest('a').attr('href',val.replace(/^([^(http://)].*)/,'http://$1'));
});
```

Comment: Do you know how i could make it go to only wwww.google.com and not http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/www.google.com? thanks

Comment: @TommyD.Adey you need to add **http://** to the link. I updated my answer to do that :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:  [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U6WNK/43/)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="test"/> <input type="button" id="go" value="go"/>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$("#go").click(function(){
    var value = $("#test").val();
    window.location = "http://"+value+"";
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say your image have this id: `#img`
Then you can use jQuery [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) to wrap the image into `a` a element:

```
$('input').change(function(){
  $('#img').wrap('<a href="' + $(this).val() + '"></a>')
})
```

DOCS: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/